# Distinct() is not giving distinct row in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

```
     DB::table('paperregisters')
         ->join('syllabuses','paperregisters.deptoffering_id','=','syllabuses.deptoffering_id')
         ->where('paperregisters.email','=',$user->email)
         ->distinct('paperregisters.admno')
         ->get();
```

I am trying to retrieve unique admno values. The above code result retrieve duplicate values. The paperregisters table has id of 1,2 and syllabuses table has id 1 , 2. i am getting result from both table

[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtTOQ.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvSUj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` instead of `distinct`

**Query**

```
DB::table('paperregisters')
             ->join('syllabuses','paperregisters.deptoffering_id','=','syllabuses.deptoffering_id')
             ->where('paperregisters.email','=',$user->email)
             ->groupBy('paperregisters.admno')
             ->get();
```

Comment: I tried this if I used groupBy i will get only one row result. i need id 1 and 2. The above code result show 1,2 from paperregisters and  1,2 from syllabuses.

Comment: what field name of `1,2` record in table

Comment: 1 and 2 are admno of both table. I have tried this Mysql I have retrieved result but I'm not getting here in laravel

Comment: so you put `your current result` and `expected result` with field name

Comment: My expected output should be i have get distinct result from paperregisters. My current result is:I'm getting result from both table

Comment: with example please @VinodS

Comment: Please check the Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a select to select the fields that you want in the final records

eg.

```
->select(['paperregisters.admno', 'syllabuses.deptoffering_id' ....])->get()
```